# Is it possible to change an API response using the host file?

Tags: vulnerability, api

Would it be possible for someone to hijack the response of an API by using the host file, so for example `www.sitename.com` calls `api.sitename.com/api/products`. Could I use the host file to redirect the call  `api.sitename.com/api/products` to a local instance of the API? If so does that vulnerability have a name?

A diagram if I'm not explaing it too well:

API normal function
[image]

An API with a mocked response
[image: API with mocked response]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can fake the price this way then this is basically due to improper validation of user input. It does not matter if the fake price comes because you've used another API endpoint (spoofing name resolution with manipulating hosts file or DNS) or if you've edited the page in the browser or if you've changed what got submitted to the server by intercepting the request - the server should never blindly trust anything which was send by the browser since what gets send is totally out of control of the server.

This means that the server would need to check if the price provided in the requested is actually the current price of the item. Or the server might send some cryptographic signature or HMAC (with a server-side secret) along with the price and can then check if the price still matches the signature/HMAC. But the server should never just blindly trust that the a price (or any other data) in the request is actually the one which was originally provided by the server.